# Erro de sintaxe incorreta próxima a engine

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria que vocês me ajudassem. Está aparecendo o seguinte erro:

> MENSAGEM 102, NÍVEL 15, ESTADO 1, LINHA 17-SINTAXE INCORRETA PRÓXIMA A `ENGINE`

porém não o encontrei.

```
CREATE TABLE SITE (
    SITE_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SITE_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_DOMAIN_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_LOGO VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_TITLE TEXT NOT NULL,
    SITE_DESCRIPTION TEXT NOT NULL,
    SITE_KEYWORDS TEXT NOT NULL,
    SITE_MENU CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_BGCOLOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_BODY_BGCOLOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_MENU_COLOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_ROLL_COLOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_MENU_FONT VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_FONT_SIZE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_ACTIVE CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'YES'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

A instrução IDENTITY(1, 1) não é válida para o MySQL (é uma instrução válida para SQL Server).

O equivalente para o MySQL é o [AUTO_INCREMENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html)

```
CREATE TABLE SITE 
(
    SITE_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    SITE_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_DOMAIN_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_LOGO VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_TITLE TEXT NOT NULL,
    SITE_DESCRIPTION TEXT NOT NULL,
    SITE_KEYWORDS TEXT NOT NULL,
    SITE_MENU CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_BGCOLOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_BODY_BGCOLOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_MENU_COLOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_ROLL_COLOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_MENU_FONT VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_FONT_SIZE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    SITE_ACTIVE CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'YES'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Note que o `AUTO_INCREMENT = 1` apenas especifica o início da sequência. Para definir o intervalo do incremento pode usar a variável [auto_increment_increment](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment), dev

Answer (score 0):

Lisa, veja se colocando o 'AUTO_INCREMENT' junto com a declaração da 'PRIMARY KEY' funciona. Assim:

```
CREATE TABLE SITE(
 SITE_ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 SITE_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 SITE_DOMAIN_NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 SITE_LOGO VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 SITE_TITLE TEXT NOT NULL,
 SITE_DESCRIPTION TEXT NOT NULL,
 SITE_KEYWORDS TEXT NOT NULL,
 SITE_MENU CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 SITE_BGCOLOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 SITE_BODY_BGCOLOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 SITE_MENU_COLOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 SITE_ROLL_COLOR VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 SITE_MENU_FONT VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 SITE_FONT_SIZE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 SITE_ACTIVE CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'YES' 
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```